How to convert Mathematica code to Python code
How to convert the following Mathematica code to Python
NDSolve[{1/(1 - f)^2.5*g''''[y] + 

       G*Sin[\[Alpha]]*((1 - f) + f*(p1*e1)/(p2*e2))*

        t'[y] - (((M^2)*A)/(1 + (A*m)^2) + 1/(k*(1 - f)^2.5))*

        g''[y] == 0, 

     b1*t''[y] + Br/(1 - f)^2.5*(g''[y])^2 + 

       Br*(((M^2)*A)/(1 + (A*m)^2) + 1/(k*(1 - f)^2.5)) (g'[y] + 

          1)^2 + \[Epsilon] == 0, g[h1] == F/2, g'[h1] == -1, 

     g[h2] == -F/2, g'[h2] == -1, t[h1] == -1/2, t[h2] == 1/2}, {g, 

     t}, {y, h1, h2}]

I tried writing the code in more than one way, but I was not able to get the code correctly that gives the same output as Mathematica

please check this

You might try asking Gemini this kind of thing. AI’s can be good at code conversion, e.g. https://g.co/gemini/share/72c23a8d57e8
Try to keep it simple though. Function by function.
